# Calling a method in another component and data will be reflected in UI

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit,HostBinding, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav-custom-component',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-nav-custom-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-nav-custom-component.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() navItems: Array<any>;
  @HostBinding('class.sidebar-nav') true;
  @HostBinding('attr.role') role;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navItems.push(
      {
        name: 'Vessels',
        url: '/vessels',
        icon: 'icon-speedometer',

      }
    );
  }

  isDivider(navItem) {
      return !!navItem.divider
  }

  isTitle(navItem) {
      return !!navItem.title
  }

  isHasChild(navItem) {
      return navItem.hasOwnProperty('children') && navItem.children.length > 0;
  }

  loadNew(){
    alert('sadasdasdasd');
    console.log('dd');

    this.navItems = []; 

    this.navItems.push(
      {
        name: 'Dashboard 2',
        url: '/dashboard',
        icon: 'icon-speedometer',

      }
    );
  }    
}
```

And the html:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <button (click)="loadNew()">test</button>
  <ng-template ngFor let-navitem [ngForOf]="navItems">
      <li *ngIf="!isHasChild(navitem)"
          [ngClass]="{'nav-title': isTitle(navitem), 'nav-item': !(isTitle(navitem) || isDivider(navitem)), 'nav-divider': isDivider(navitem)}"
      >
          <span *ngIf="isTitle(navitem)">{{navitem.name}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="isDivider(navitem)"></span>
          <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!(isTitle(navitem) || isDivider(navitem))" routerLink="{{navitem.url}}"
             routerLinkActive="active">
              <i class="nav-icon" [ngClass]="navitem.icon"></i> {{navitem.name}}
          </a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isHasChild(navitem)" appNavDropdown routerLinkActive="open" class="nav-item nav-dropdown open">
          <a appNavDropdownToggle class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" role="button"><i class="nav-icon" [ngClass]="navitem.icon"></i> {{navitem.name}}</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
              <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let cnavitem of navitem.children">
                  <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!(isTitle(cnavitem) || isDivider(cnavitem))" routerLink="{{cnavitem.url}}"
                     routerLinkActive="active">
                      <i class="nav-icon" [ngClass]="cnavitem.icon"></i> {{cnavitem.name}}
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ng-template>
</ul>
```

If I click the button in the component it self all items are removed as expected.

However if I call the function loadMenu from a other component, the method is called, but the UI dosent update? Its like navItems has its own instance. How would you control the navItems from another component, and make the UI update?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent} from '../sidebar-nav-custom-component/sidebar-nav-custom-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vessels',
  templateUrl: './vessels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vessels.component.scss']
})
export class VesselsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidebar: SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadMenu(){
    alert('lol');
    this.sidebar.loadNew();
  }

}
```

Comment: Well this can be achieved by Angular Ngrx Store! https://coursetro.com/posts/code/151/Angular-Ngrx-Store-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-State-Management

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its just communication by two components, so having it saved i some storage is maybe overkill. Is it because a new instance is created or what is the reason that the UI dosent update when call is done from another controller?

Comment: Notice the sidebar component is placed in the app.component html file, so it should be loaded at all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your goal

Its pretty clear that you want to have communication between different Components.

### Issues ?

There are couple of issues in your implementation

1. Injecting the Component reference. Its not a good very practice until and unless you want to manipulate the DOM.
2. Issue is with new reference of array to variable `navItems`. Instead of assigning the new value you can empty the existing array and push the new items in it.

### Solution

As per your requirement you should create the service which will act a bridge among different component. This service class will notify all the component is anything is changed.

### Example

> data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject();

  getData(){
     return this.messageSource.asObservable();
  }

  reloadData() {
    let data = [{
    name: 'Dashboard 2',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',

  }];
    this.messageSource.next(data); //notify all that data is loaded.
  }

}
```

> app-sidebar-nav-custom-component.ts

```
export class SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() navItems: Array<any>;
  @HostBinding('class.sidebar-nav') true;
  @HostBinding('attr.role') role;

  constructor(private dataService : DataService) {
       this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
          this.navItems = data;  //update the data whenever data is updated in service.
       });
   }
}
```

> app-vessels.ts

```
Finally you can update the data

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent} from '../sidebar-nav-custom-component/sidebar-nav-custom-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vessels',
  templateUrl: './vessels.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vessels.component.scss']
})
export class VesselsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidebar: SidebarNavCustomComponentComponent, private dataService : DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadMenu(){
    this.dataService.realoadData(); //reload new data. 
  }

}
```

> Final notes :

1. Do not forget to put the DataService in providers array of module.
2. Code written above was typed straight to `stackoverflow` so there could be some minor issues related typo or syntactical errors. So correct yourself.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! Good old service it is.

Answer (score 0):

Angular performs change detection on all components (from top to bottom) every time something changes in your app from something like a user event or data received from a network request. Change detection is very performant, but as an app gets more complex and the amount of components grows, change detection will have to perform more and more work. There’s a way to circumvent that however and set the change detection strategy to OnPush on specific components. Doing this will instruct Angular to run change detection on these components and their sub-tree only when new references are passed to them versus when data is simply mutated.

Take a look at [Change Detection Strategy in Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/)